# Magento 2 Css problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css

I am using Devilbox and these specifications :

```
PHP_SERVER = 7.3
MYSQL_SERVER=mysql-5.7
HTTPD_SERVER=apache-2.4
```

I have cloned the project and I have launched these commands

From phpmyadmin

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

and this one

```
bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento s:static-content:deploy es_ES en_US de_DE fr_FR -f
```

from Devilbox Shell but nothing has worked , always I got Page containing HTML without CSS
There is no CSS render and I got always this message in the console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

That it is shown for CSS , JS and fonts resources.
I have tried also to empty the cache and nothing works 
If anyone needs any other details you could ask me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the file permissions issue. Run these commands and check again.

chmod -R 777 var/;

chmod -R 777 pub/static/;

chmod -R 777 generated/;

Comment: I have used chmod -R 777 var/

Comment: Set 777 for pub/static and generated directory too

Comment: ok I will check with that and I 'll inform you

Comment: Thanks but that changes nothing, what may I do after thoses lines concerning 'chmod'

Comment: Can you share the url of css ?